# Firebase remote config fails on fetchAndActivate

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-remote-config

My web app uses Firebase Remote Config to fetch some details about a survey for the user. <strike>When I run `firebase.remoteConfig().getValue('survey_message');` it returns the correct value.</strike> That was a cached value and after clearing it, it now returns an empty string.

When I try `firebase.remoteConfig().fetchAndActivate()` or `.fetch()` it fails with these error messages:

[image: error messages]

In the Network tab I'm also gettings a couple of 403 errors from `authTokens:generate` which appear when I try `remoteConfig().fetch()`

[image: error 403s]

I'm note sure why it works with `getValue()` but not the others - does anyone have any ideas how to fix this as it's affecting my users.